# BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT passing arguments as values

Tags: c++, boost, scope

Could you please tell me if this is a good programming practice:

```
  bool x = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
    BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT(x, i)
    {

        if (x)
        {
            std::cout << " Hello" << " i " << i << " " << std::endl;
        }
    } BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT_END

    if(i == 5)
    {
        x = true;
    }
  }
```

I am passing by value:

```
  BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT(x, i)
```

and not

```
  BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT(&x, &i).
```

======

The output is:

```
 Hello i 6 
 Hello i 7 
 Hello i 8 
 Hello i 9
```

So it does work.

The value with :

BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT(&x, &i)

The values are diffirent.

```
Hello i 5
```

Gets printed as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both need to be a reference since you need to access the final value.

You should be able to validate this by running your program with different values and seeing that 'Hello' is never printed out with the code as-is.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/libs/scope_exit/doc/html/scope_exit/tutorial.html

Comment: I see what you meant. I will edit my question with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to c++11 or better I would argue that good programming practice would be to move with the times. BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT is now redundant:

```
#include <iostream>

// -- snip -- this into a header file
namespace detail {
    template<class Function>
    struct at_scope_exit
    {
        at_scope_exit(Function f) : _f(std::move(f)) {}
        ~at_scope_exit() {
            try {
                _f();
            }
            catch(...) {

            }
        }
        Function _f;
    };
}

template<class Function>
auto at_scope_exit(Function f) -> detail::at_scope_exit<Function>
{
    return { std::move(f) };
}
// -- end snip --

auto main() -> int
{
    std::cout << "By Reference:\n";
    // using by reference:
    {
        int i = 0;
        bool x = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            // reference to x is taken here
            auto endscope = at_scope_exit([&x, i] {
                if (x) {
                    std::cout << " Hello" << " i " << i << " " << std::endl;
                }
            });

            if(i == 5)
            {
                x = true;
            }
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\nBy Value:\n";
    // using by value
    {
        int i = 0;
        bool x = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            // COPY OF x is taken here
            auto endscope = at_scope_exit([x, i] {
                if (x) {
                    std::cout << " Hello" << " i " << i << " " << std::endl;
                }
            });

            if(i == 5)
            {
                // x set HERE (after the above copy) so it's now different to the lambda's version of x
                x = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
By Reference:
 Hello i 5 
 Hello i 6 
 Hello i 7 
 Hello i 8 
 Hello i 9 

By Value:
 Hello i 6 
 Hello i 7 
 Hello i 8 
 Hello i 9
```

Comment: I understand. My project uses boost and we as of now are not moving to C++11.

Comment: Could you please let me know why yours print 5 and mine doesn't if I pass by value.

Comment: mine would not print 5 if I passed by value because if you pass by value, x is copied at the time the code flows over the creation of the lambda. This is *before* x gets set to true on the 6th iteration. If you pass by reference, the value of x is tested by the lambda *after* x is set to true on the 6th iteration so the at-exit code is executed one iteration earlier.